# How to remove gaps between rows displaying in the SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2017

I have design report in such a way that rows should display only filtered data based on where "RECORDTYPE=ALL" and another row where "RECORDTYPE=GD" and corresponding columns also filter and fill data by RECORDTYPE.

For design purpose,I created Table with first row as below condition

[image]

I tried to use option,"InsertRow-->OutsideGroup- Below",but not able to retrieve data based on Record Type.
So,I created another row group based RECORDTYPE as shown below
[image]

[image]

After setting this condition,when I preview the report,I see gaps between rows and I am not sure why the gaps are coming.Please let me know how can we remove gap between rows.

[image]

Comment: The expression for the date will display a blank if the `RECORD_TYPE <> 'ALL' `. Should you filter these out instead?

Comment: @HannoverFist - I tried something on RowGroup like Expression "RECORD_TYPE" <> "ALL" for first group.But still space is showing

Comment: I tried with another option By adding "Parent group" and groupy by Record_Type and hide the Group textboxes and the result is showing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Hannover Fist's comment, the empty rows are probably showing up because there are rows with empty or NULL data (of the columns used in the tablix) coming back in the data set.

If you filter out empty records from the Tablix (Tablix Properties >> Filters) or from the Row Group (Group Properties >> Filters), those rows won't show.